# Kinect: Calculate head's pitch, yaw, roll angles

Tags: c#, kinect

I am trying to use Kinect sensor and SDK to calculate the orientation of user's head but I wasn't able to find any good help for this on google. Does anybody have any good sample, tutorial or something like that that might help me?

Comment: Are you looking at the orientation while capturing the full skeleton of a standing player, or is the player seated closer to the Kinect sensor?  You may be able to the `FaceTracking` functions to obtain this information (if the player is close), but head orientation is not part of the regular skeleton data structure.

Comment: I would prefer it for a standing player, but if this isn't possible then I can settle with a seated one close to the sensor. I'm aware that I could use the FaceTracking but the problem is if the user for example turns his head too much to the right the FaceTracker will lose its mappings.

Comment: You'd need to look into extending on the `FaceTracking` functions, or write your own (might as well use what exists as a base though).  The `FaceTracking` code may still be able to follow important points, even when it doesn't have enough to render a face mesh.  I've not worked with the example much though, so I'm not sure.  The "out of the box" features of the SDK unfortunately do not have the values you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I have found a solution although it's limited, it works only if the Kinect SDK can detect the face since I'm using the `FaceTrackFrame` object.

If somebody finds a solution to track more extreme angles when Kinect SDK is unable to detect a face I'd be more then happy to see it.

My solution looks something like this:

```
       FaceTrackFrame faceFrame = faceTracker.Track(
            kinectSensor.ColorStream.Format, colorPixelData,
            kinectSensor.DepthStream.Format, depthPixelData, skeleton);

        // Only works if face is detected
        if (faceFrame.TrackSuccessful)
        {
            txtTracked.Content = "TRACKED";
            txtRoll.Content = faceFrame.Rotation.Z;
            txtPitch.Content = faceFrame.Rotation.X;
            txtYaw.Content = faceFrame.Rotation.Y;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to calculate these manually using the depth data from the image.

First you need to get the depth point

```
    private EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, Vector3DF> depthPoints;
```

Then if you look at the FaceTracking viewer code that comes with the SDK and search for the DrawFaceModel function. You can extract the code like this in the 1st for loop.

```
    faceModelPts3D.Add(new Point3D(this.depthPoints[i].X + 0.5f, this.depthPoints[i].Y + 0.5f, this.depthPoints[i].Z + 0.5f));
    FaceDataPoints.DepthXPointInfo[i] = this.depthPoints[i].X;
    FaceDataPoints.DepthYPointInfo[i] = this.depthPoints[i].Y;
    FaceDataPoints.DepthZPointInfo[i] = this.depthPoints[i].Z;
```

I then placed point 0 and point 9 into the following function to obtain the Pitch. I then put the Points 120 and 116 in to obtain the yawn angle.

```
    public static double FacePitch(double FirstXPos, double FirstYPos, double FirstZPos, double SecXPos, double SecYPos, double SecZPos)
    {
        double PitchAngle = 0;
        double r = 0;
        double XDifference, YDifference, ZDifference = 0;
        double DifferenceSquared = 0;

        XDifference = FirstXPos - SecXPos;//Calculates distance from Points 
        YDifference = FirstYPos - SecYPos;
        ZDifference = FirstZPos - SecZPos;

        DifferenceSquared = Math.Pow(XDifference, 2) + Math.Pow(YDifference, 2) + Math.Pow(ZDifference, 2);

        r = Math.Sqrt(DifferenceSquared);

        PitchAngle = (Math.Acos(ZDifference / r));

        PitchAngle = ((PitchAngle * 180 / Math.PI) - 90) * -1; //Converts to Degrees as easier to recognise visually 

        return PitchAngle;
    }
```

for the roll i placed point 0 and 9 in again and used the above function again But i changed

```
PitchAngle = (Math.Acos(ZDifference / r));
```

to

```
RollAngle = Math.Acos(XDifference / r);
```

Comment: does the user need to be close for this or are you able to calculate these number from a distance?

Comment: It seems to function as long as the SDK can detect the users face

Comment: Very nice.  I look forward to trying it!

Comment: Do you know about 'frame.Rotation'? I've realized that I can get the angles with that property as well, for example 'frame.Rotation.Z' would give me Roll, and X and Y would give me the other two angles. The problem with this solution is that it can track the angles only if the SDK can detect the face, similar limitation as to your solution.

Comment: No I wasn't aware of the frame rotation, so I might have to give that a go as well at some point.